How to arrange Spring Batch chunk processing with online transactions
The system has simultaneous batch jobs and online workflows. Consider batch job retrieving unprocessed documents, marking them as processed in the chunk transaction. Chunk processing is required for performance and reliability reasons.
During job running, person deceased message is received. Process finds all unprocessed documents of person deleting them. The collision of batch processing and online architecture is problematic.

Problem 1: Another process may find documents being processed but not committed
To mitigate this problem, I can use write locks in both ends. When documents are being processed in uncommitted transaction, selecting those rows in another transaction blocks until the commit of first transaction.
Problem 2: Another process may get partial result between chunks
This happens even with row-locking in place. Another process may find documents not yet processed, but to be processed by the running batch job. This is hard to mitigate as chunk order is in essence random. One solution would be to block any person deceased process during batch job. That would be waste of response time, if finished batch job didn't process documents of blocked person.

Is there some patterns or best practices to solve this synchronization problem? I need absolute consistency and maximum response time possible without sacrificing consistency.
